# Can I get the password for custom AMI Image Amazon Web service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I had an Windows Instance in Amazon that I had RDPed in and installed needed softwares to make it as a build server. I took a snapshot(AMI) and terminated this instance. Unfortunately I hadn't noted down its password. Now when I start a new instance using that Image (AMI) I am not able to login. Is there a way that I can get or reset the password from AWS?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-passwords.html hope it helps :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt help to get the password, but instead I was able to reset the password and then took another snapshot, So that I was able to use this new snapshot instead of the old one.